# #1052 - La columna: 'idUsuarios' en field list es ambigua

Tags: mysql, sql

hola Buenas agradecería su ayuda para mi duda, soy nuevo en esto y la verdad no se como hacerlo

este código lo ingreso en mysql, y me marca el error de arriba

```
SELECT p.idRegistroP, (p.Usuarios), (p.PagoAgua)
as idUsuarios, (u.Nombres)
as Nombres, idUsuarios, (u.Apellidos)
as Apellidos, idPago, (t.Mes)
as Mes, idPago, (t.Ayear)
as Ayear
FROM registropago p
INNER JOIN usuarios i ON p.Usuarios = i.idUsuarios
INNER JOIN usuarios u ON p.Usuarios = u.idUsuarios
INNER JOIN usuarios v ON p.Usuarios = v.idUsuarios
INNER JOIN pagoagua t ON p.PagoAgua = t.idPago
INNER JOIN pagoagua q ON p.PagoAgua = q.idPago
WHERE idRegistroP = 4
```

se que es por que llamo dos campos de la misma tabla pero la verdad es que no se como hacer que no marque este error.

muchas gracias por su atención.

Comment: Procura cambiar :"as Nombres, idUsuarios, (u.Apellidos)"  POR  ESTO: "as Nombres, idUsuarios2, (u.Apellidos)" Y Avisa si desaparece el error

Comment: lo realice y me salio error jejeje #1054 - La columna 'idUsuarios2' en field list es desconocida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando el motor te indica que una columna es ambigua se origina por que:

Mas de una de tus tablas involucradas en la consulta tienen una columna con el mismo nombre, entonces el motor no sabe determinar por cual de todas ellas construir tu consulta.

Puedes proceder de este modo:

Indica el nombre de la tabla y seguido con un punto en medio la columna a la cual apuntas.

Ejemplo:

```
Nombres, TuTabla1.idUsuarios, (u.Apellidos)
```

Donde:

- `TuTabla1` será el nombre de la entidad de la cual usarás dicha columna, con lo cual se hace exacta su identificación

O bien si por alguna razón necesitas hacer un `SELECT` mas de una vez de la misma columna de la misma tabla o de una tabla distinta y ambas tienen el mismo nombre, entonces colócale un alias, es decir

```
tabla.miColumna1 AS nuevoNombre1, tabla.miColumna1 AS nuevoNombre2
```